Como utilizar 'TBookmark'
estoy programando en Delphi XV una RELACION FAMILIAR. Tengo en un formulario Modulo todos los query, tdatasour, tzconexion, etc. Desde otro formulario tengo un dbgrid, este al ejecutarlo traigo la info. de una tabla a traves de un tzreadOnlyQuery (Zeos). El sistema me permite seleccionar la primera fila y editarla (EDIT), luego selecciono otras filas y genero relaciones familiares. Hasta ahi de 10.
Alguien podria orientarme como realizar esto:

Lo que necesito es que al SELECCIONAR la primera fila (La que se va a editar) esta NO PUEDA SER SELECCIONADA Enabled

Luego de seleccionar la segunda fila, el puntero regresa a la primera fila seleccionada.

Por ultimo si selecciona una fila anteriormente seleccionada salte un alerta que no es posible seleccionar esa fila.
fModulo.tRel_Persona.Active := true;
if fModulo.tRel_Persona.Locate('id_Rel_Persona'),[]) = true
then begin
fmodulo.tRel_Persona.Edit;
end;



fModulo.tRel_Persona.Active := true;
if fModulo.tRel_Persona.Locate('id_Rel_Persona'),[]) = true
then
begin
fmodulo.tRel_Persona.Edit;
end;

Hola, bienvenido a SO.
Cuando añadas código utiliza el TAG de código para que se vea correctamente.
En cuanto a la explicación no se entiende muy bien lo que pretendes. Si seleccionas la PRIMERA no se pueda editar, si seleccionas la SEGUNDA que pase a la PRIMERA (que no se puede editar) y si seleccionas la anterior (No se entiende si es la PRIMERA o la SEGUNDA) que no se pueda seleccionar.  Por la explicación creo que estás mezclando filas en el DGBrid de diferentes tablas y lo intentas "arreglar" con este comportamiento que es "raro". Los bookmarks no se qué relación tienen aquí.

Buenas German. En sintesis, necsito que al seleccionar una fila de registro esta yano se pueda seleccionar y al terminar el proceso me devuelva el foco en la primera fila seleccionada del DBGrid

Cuando hablas de seleccionar la primera fila, ¿haces algún proceso con ella? Hablas de "terminar un proceso", pero no lo explicas. Si es lo que pienso, lo normal sería que "esa fila" (registro en Base de Datos) tuviera una marca (un campo booleano) y que una vez realizado el proceso le pusieras un TRUE.
Al marcar otra fila (registro) deberás comprobar si ya hay alguna fila que tenga la marca y seleccionarla.
